# spritekitでプレイヤーが移動した時に、壁に当たったら動かない様にしたい

Tags: spritekit

どうやってもプレイヤーが壁を押してしまいます、どうすれば、skactionなどで移動したプレイヤー（RPG想定）が、壁に当たった時にそこで止まる様な仕様を実装できますか？

画面のピンク色の長方形の部分のNodeは川になっていて、歩行中のプレイヤーが歩けないようにしたくて、テクスチャーは入れずにダイナミックを入れ、Massを100くらいにしたりして、プレイヤーが接触したらそこで止まる様にしたいのですが、何をどうしても、SKActionやCGvecterで移動したプレイヤーがこのNodeを押してしまいます。
PindにしてもプライヤーのMassやdentityを0にしても押してしまいます。プレイヤーの動きをはねのける様な、そんな壁の存在が欲しいのです。

```java
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var textureSide:[SKTexture] = []
    var textureUp:[SKTexture]   = []
    var textureDown:[SKTexture] = []

    var upB:SKSpriteNode!
    var downB:SKSpriteNode!
    var rightB:SKSpriteNode!
    var leftB:SKSpriteNode!

    var playerposition = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    var yellow:SKSpriteNode!

    var player:SKSpriteNode!
    var wall:SKSpriteNode!

    var rightpoti = true

    enum direction {
        case right
        case left
        case up
        case down    
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

        wall = self.childNode(withName: "wall") as! SKSpriteNode
        wall.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        wall.zPosition = 5

        player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "walkman8")
        player.position = playerposition
        player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        player.zPosition = 2
        player.setScale(2)
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.frame.size)
        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
        player.physicsBody?.density = 1
        player.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        player.physicsBody?.restitution = 2
        addChild(player)

        upB = self.childNode(withName: "upB") as! SKSpriteNode
        downB = self.childNode(withName: "downB") as! SKSpriteNode
        rightB = self.childNode(withName: "rightB")  as! SKSpriteNode
        leftB = self.childNode(withName: "leftB")  as! SKSpriteNode

        yellow = self.childNode(withName: "yellow") as! SKSpriteNode
        yellow.position = CGPoint(x: -0, y: -600)

        let atras = SKTextureAtlas(named: "walker")

        for i in 1...3{
            textureSide.append(atras.textureNamed("walkman" + String(i)))
        }

        for i in 6...7{
            textureDown.append(atras.textureNamed("walkman" + String(i)))
        }

        for i in 8...10{
            textureUp.append(atras.textureNamed("walkman" + String(i)))
        }

        let animation = SKAction.animate(with: textureDown, timePerFrame: 0.6 )
        player.run(SKAction.repeatForever(animation))
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("bodyA:\(String(describing: contact.bodyA.node?.name))")

        if contact.bodyA == wall  {
            player.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: 30, duration: 1))
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            if self.atPoint(location) == upB {
                movePlayer(Direction: .up)
            }
            if self.atPoint(location) == downB {
                movePlayer(Direction: .down)
            }
            if self.atPoint(location) == leftB {
                movePlayer(Direction: .left)
            }
            if self.atPoint(location) == rightB {
                movePlayer(Direction: .right)
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    }

    func movePlayer(Direction:direction){
        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 100)
    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらの質問ですが、動かなくてもよいので、実際のコード片を交えつつ具体的に問題を説明して頂くことは可能でしょうか？　どういうコードで、予想していた挙動は何で、実際の挙動は何だったのかの3点を書いて頂けると分かりやすいと思います。質問文の下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、そちらからお願いいたします。

Comment: ご助言感謝いたします。
swift一年目で、spritekitは１か月目で右も左もわからず、立ち往生しておりました。RPGをspritekitで作りたく奔走しておりました、質問内容以外にも何かしらアドバイスやコードのコツなどありましたら、ご指摘くださると大変嬉しいです。

Comment: 貼り付け時のミスなのか`movePlayer`の定義が途中で途切れているようなので、再度見直しをお願いします。

Comment: override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    }
    
    func movePlayer(Direction:direction){
        
        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 100)
        
        
           
        
      
        
        
    }
    
}
コードはここまでです。とりあえず、Playerがピンクの長方形を押さないようにしたくて、シンプルにこれだけにしています。
途中で切れてしまっていて申し訳ありません。あとユーティリティーエリアの設定とコードにいる設定では、インスタンスに与える影響はどちらが優先されるのかがいまひとつつかめず困惑しています。

Comment: 重力や衝突の影響を受けないようなノードを作成する場合は、通常Dynamicをオフにするはずですが、なぜ「ダイナミックを入れ」ているのでしょうか? なお、コードの修正はコメントではなく、本文の方の編集を行ってください。

Comment: 申し訳ありません、すぐに本文を修正します。Dynamicを入れているのはオフにした時に、キャラクターがピンクの正方形の上を移動し始めた（川の上を歩いちゃった）ので、接触させないとダメかと思い、入れました。するとそれが最後どうやっても、プレイヤーの動作をピンクの場所で抑えられず、移動の度にピンクを押し出し、川の中をモーゼのように歩いてしまうという・・・・感じです。

Comment: 本文の修正ありがとうございました。コードの整形は最初の行から最後の行までを選択状態にして編集領域の`{}`アイコンをクリックするだけ(全部の行に前4個の空白が入るだけですが)ですのでお試しください。Dynamicについては、所望の動作をさせるための試行錯誤の一つであって、それ以外の意図はないと言うことでよろしいでしょうか。あなたがお持ちのsksファイルがないので、不完全かもしれませんが、とりあえず修正しなければいけないと考えられる点を回答にまとめてみますので、後ほどご確認ください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まずは、`SKPhysicsBody`の各プロパティがどのような意味を持つか、きちんと理解しましょう。

### [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody)

長文ですが、(Appleのリファレンスページにしては珍しく)コード例も多数ありますし、ざっくり眺めて、どこにどんなことが書いてあるのか程度は頭に入れておいた方が良いでしょう。

- [`isDynamic`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520132-isdynamic) (sksエディタのDynamicに相当)

  物理シミュレーションの対象になるかどうかを決定します。物理シミュレーションというのは要は衝突時の反動や重力による影響を言います。よって「衝突時の反動で動いちゃダメ」なら必ず`false`(エディタ上ではチェックを入れない)にします。
- [`categoryBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519869-categorybitmask)(Category Mask)と[`collisionBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520003-collisionbitmask)(Collision Mask)

  衝突処理を行うかどうかは、あるノードの`categoryBitMask`の値と相手ノードの`collisionBitMask`の値によって決定されます。決定には二進法が絡むので、後でもうちょっと説明します。

  あなたが当初「キャラクターがピンクの正方形の上‌​を移動し始めた（川の上を歩いちゃった）」という動作を見られたのは、このプロパティが適切に設定されていなかったためと考えられます。
- `categoryBitMask`と[`contactTestBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519781-contacttestbitmask)(Contact Mask)

  `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`による接触判定の対象になるかどうかを決定します。要は`didBegin(_:)`のような接触判定用のメソッドが呼び出されるかどうかを制御します。

---

### `categoryBitMask`と`collisionBitMask`の設定の仕方

あなたがご所望の動作をさせるためには、「壁」は物理シミュレーションで動いてはいけないが、「壁」と「プレイヤー」は衝突処理を行わないといけない、のでこれらを正しく設定しないといけません。

#### `categoryBitMask`の設定

衝突処理・接触判定を考えて、画面上に表示されるノードを何種類かにカテゴリ分けして、それぞれに別のビットを割り当てておきます。

(例)
プレーヤーキャラ `0b0001` (10進法だと1)
敵キャラ　　　　 `0b0010` (2)
不動の障害物　　 `0b0100` (4)

※SpriteKitの紹介記事ではシフト演算(`<<`)を使っている場合が多いですが、Swiftでは2進法のリテラルが書けるので、その方がわかりやすいように思います。実際には32種類まで指定できますが、長くなるので4ビット分しか示していません。(他の28ビットは全部0。)
※あなたの画面写真では壁のこの項目が0になってしまっていますが、これでは衝突処理や接触判定の対象にはなりません。(*)

#### `collisionBitMask`の設定

衝突処理を行いたい相手の`categoryBitMask`を設定します。`categoryBitMask`はそれぞれ別のビットに指定されているはずなので、相手を複数指定することができます。

(例)
プレーヤーキャラ⇒敵キャラと不動の障害物に対して衝突処理を行う
`0b0110` (6) ※敵キャラの`categoryBitMask` `0b0010`と不動の障害物の`0b0100`を指定

敵キャラ⇒プレーヤーキャラと不動の障害物に対して衝突処理を行う
`0b0101` (5) ※プレーヤーキャラの`0b0001`と不動の障害物の`0b0100`を指定

不動の障害物⇒プレーヤーキャラと敵キャラに対して衝突処理を行う
`0b0011` (4) ※プレーヤーキャラの`0b0001`と敵キャラの`0b0010`を指定

(*) 上記のように衝突には2つのノードが関わるのでどちらに設定すべきかというところですが、他の設定項目によっては、片方だけの設定ではうまくいかない場合があります。「プレーヤー⇒不動の障害物」「不動の障害物⇒プレーヤー」の双方の視点から矛盾無い設定にしておいた方が良いでしょう。

#### `contactTestBitMask`の設定

上記`collisionBitMask`と同様の考え方で設定してください。デリゲートメソッドの呼び出しは、SpriteKit的には重い処理になるので、可能な限り接触判定の相手は少なめに設定した方が良いでしょう。

---

### コードでは

以下のような設定を、`didMove(to:)`メソッド内の適当な場所に追加してみてください。もちろんsksエディタ上でどの場所にどんな値を入れれば良いかが理解出来ていれば、そちらの修正だけでコードの方はいじらなくても大丈夫のはずです。

```
    wall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    wall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0b0100 //<- 不動の障害物用のビット
    wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b0011 //<- プレーヤーの`categoryBitMask`を含める
    wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0b0011

    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0b0001 //<- プレーヤー用のビット
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b0110 //<- 不動の障害物用の`categoryBitMask`を含める
    player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0b0100 //<- 壁との接触判定は行うが、敵キャラ(まだあなたのコードにはないですが)との接触判定はない、という設定
```

---

ご質問へのコメントに書いたように、あなたのプロジェクト全部を参照できるわけではありませんので、上記の修正だけで確実にご所望の動作になるかはわかりません。何かありましたら、コメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: すごく丁寧にたっぷり解説していただいてありがとうございます、ただいま帰宅し、確認しました。これを熟読して、試して、改めて報告させていただきます、本当にご親切に細かい部分まで詳述していただいて感激です。勉強不足でした、もっと邁進いたします。

Comment: @るーず さん、コメントでも回答本文でも`isDynamic`を`false`にと書いてあるのにコードの部分が`true`になってしまっていました。そこら辺の誤りがすぐわかる程度に熟読していただいたのだと思いますが、今後同じ問題を抱えてサイトを訪れる方はそこまでしっかり読まれないかもしれません。回答の中に誤りや改善すべき点を見つけたらご指摘いただけると助かります。失礼しました。

Comment: Dynamicをfalseにするとう事を最初の投稿で明言されていたので、そこは逆に気づきませんでした。Bitmaskが０だとどうなるかなど、そのあたりの理解が曖昧でそこで壁にぶち当たっていました。（playerは壁に当たれないのに）。わかりました、以後は間違いなどを発見したら指摘するようにいたします。

Comment: @るーず さん、大きく混乱させたのでなければよかったです。注文めいた書き方になってしまい失礼しましたが、承認後の回答も編集することができて、よりよいQ&A集となることを目指すというこのサイトの特性をご理解いただいて、お時間が許す範囲でご協力いただければと思います。良いアプリを。