# SpriteKit、Swift4にて、衝突判定（didBegin）が動作しない

Tags: swift, ios, spritekit, swift4

現在Swift4のSpriteKitにて、シューティングゲームを製作しております。
その中で必要な衝突判定（didBegin）が動かなく、困っております。

## 該当のソースコード

```
//Swift4、Xcode9、iOS 11.2（最新版）を利用し、ビルドシステムはデフォルトのものを使用しております。
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import Foundation

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

let playerjudge = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 2.5)
let enemy1 = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "ghost.sks")

let category_player:UInt32 = 1 << 1 // 000001
let category_graze:UInt32 = 1 << 2  // 000010
let category_playerbullet:UInt32 = 1 << 4 // 000100
let category_enemy1:UInt32 = 1 << 10       // 001000
let category_enemybullet1:UInt32 = 1 << 20 // 010000
let category_other:UInt32 = 1 << 40        // 100000

private var bullet : SKShapeNode?


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    // 物理衝突の情報を自分で受け取る
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    // 物理空間の外枠の種類は、その他
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category_other
    
    playerjudge.strokeColor = .red
    playerjudge.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 2)
    playerjudge.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    addChild(playerjudge)
    playerjudge.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category_player
    self.bullet = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
    
    enemy1!.xScale = enemy1!.xScale / 2.5
    enemy1!.yScale = enemy1!.yScale / 2.5
    enemy1!.position.x = frame.midX
    enemy1!.position.y = frame.midY + 150
    enemy1!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
    addChild(enemy1!)
    enemy1!.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    enemy1!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category_enemy1
    if let bullet = self.bullet {
        bullet.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), duration: 1)))
        bullet.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5),
                                      SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.5),
                                      SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
    }
}

func playershot() {
    if let n = self.bullet?.copy() as! SKShapeNode? {
        n.position = playerjudge.position
        n.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 12.5)
        n.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        self.addChild(n)
        n.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category_playerbullet
        n.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), duration: 0.1)))
        n.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: n.position.x, y: n.position.y + 350, duration:0.75),
                                 SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.5),
                                 SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let location = touches.first!.location(in: self)
    let action = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:location.x, y:location.y + 50), duration:0.1)
    playerjudge.run(action)
    playershot()
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}

//ここの衝突判定のプログラムが機能していないようで、ログに衝突と表示されない。
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("衝突")
    if contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == category_playerbullet && contact.bodyB.node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == category_enemy1{
        contact.bodyA.node!.removeFromParent()
        contact.bodyB.node!.removeFromParent()
    }else if contact.bodyB.node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == category_playerbullet && contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == category_enemy1{
        contact.bodyA.node!.removeFromParent()
        contact.bodyB.node!.removeFromParent()
    }
}
}
```

回答よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/107217

Comment: 接触判定の`didBegin(_:)`を呼び出させるようにするには、各physicsBodyの`categoryBitMask`の他に`contactTestBitMask`を設定しないといけない(デフォルトは0、一切接触判定をしない)のですが、あなたのコードの中にはまったく`contactTestBitMask`を設定している部分がありません。`contactTestBitMask`はiOSにSpriteKitが紹介されたごく初期の時期には不要だったのですが、極めてわずかな期間だったので、きちんと最新のiOSに対応した書籍やサイトでは`contactTestBitMask`の設定の仕方も紹介されています。`contactTestBitMask`はおまけ扱いですが、基本的な考え方は`collisionBitMask`も`contactTestBitMask`も同じなので、[こちらの記事](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/40337/13972)も参考にしてみてください。

Comment: また現在の接触判定には入っていないようですが、`category_other`の設定も根本的に間違っています。`UInt32`というデータ型からわかるように32ビットしかないデータ型の値を40ビットもシフトすれば全部の値が溢れてしまいます。(現在のSwiftだと結果が0になる。)シフト後の値とシフトするビット数の区別が全くついていないようですし、その値についても10進表記と16進数や8進数がごっちゃになっているようです。ここら辺の理解が不十分なのであれば、上のコメントにあげた記事のように最初から二進表記を使われた方がいいでしょう。

Comment: 御回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。